# How do I display Image from ftp server like 5gbfree

Tags: php, laravel, server, ftp, storage

Hello I'm developing a blog using Laravel framework and I'm stuck now ,
because I want to diplay profile picture retrieved from FTP server "5gbfree" but I can't get the URL ERROR messag said the the your driver doesn't support URLs.

I want to know how I can retrieve images and display them as  HTML tag with src property or there is another method to retrieve non-public photos from FTP server.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to retrieve the image ?